# How to disable PyCharm from automatically updating Python interpreter on startup

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, anaconda

It seems that PyCharm always updates the connected Python interpreter on startup and also scans and updates all packages if needed. For me this means whenever I open PyCharm there will be updating processes running in background and I have to wait sometimes for as good as a whole minute, which I find quite annoying.

So the question is: does there exist any way to disable this automatic update mechanism? It would be best if I can manually update Python interpreter and the packages *only if I want to*.

Comment: fwiw, this issue is discussed here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30306

Answer (score 1):

Open PyCharm.

Go to "File" -> "Settings" (or "PyCharm" -> "Preferences" on macOS).

In the Settings/Preferences dialog, navigate to "Project: <your_project_name>" -> "Python Interpreter."

In the Python Interpreter settings, uncheck the option that says something like "Automatically check for available packages."

Click "OK" to save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/update.html#standalone:

> Disable automatic update checks﻿ In the Settings/Preferences dialog Ctrl+Alt+S, select Appearance and Behavior | System Settings | Updates.
>
> Clear the Automatically check updates for checkbox.

Answer (score -2):

From the official [PyCharm help forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205436490-Is-there-a-way-to-disable-automatic-update-checking-during-installation-):

> You need to update the cofiguration file at / with the following code

```
<application>
 <component name="UpdatesConfigurable">
   <option name="CHECK_NEEDED" value="false" />
 </component>
</application>
```

Comment: This is about checking updates of PyCharm itself. This has nothing to do with updating the packages in the interpreter.

Answer (score -2):

From the [PyCharm help page:](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/update.html#standalone)

> You can manage PyCharm updates on the Updates page under Appearance
> and Behavior | System Settings in the Settings/Preferences dialog
> Ctrl+Alt+S: Disable automatic update checks﻿
>
> In the Settings/Preferences dialog Ctrl+Alt+S, select Appearance and
> Behavior | System Settings | Updates.
>
> Clear the Automatically check updates for checkbox.

Answer (score -2):

You can manually update the package and change the interpreter settings by following either of the two ways:-

**Method-1**: you have to go to the edit configuration button situated at the topmost right screen of your pycharm window and after clicking on it select the interpreter you want from the list.

**Method-2**: Go to system settings (in Windows) or system preferences (in mac) and then select a project interpreter from the dropdown menu. From there, you can change interpreter settings as well as install packages from the '+' sign.

Answer (score -3):

If you want choose and update the Python interpreter in use for your project only when you want, you can set the **Project Interpreter** to Virtualenv.

From the menu File -> Settings you should choose:

- Project: name of the project
- Project Interpreter
- Add...from the icon: [gear icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSrKo.png)

On section **Virtualenv Environment** choose **New environment** and the version of **Base Interpreter**